Trying to connect to SQL server in VBA
Function test(variable as string)

Dim CS as String
Dim CN as Object
Dim DB as Object

set CS = "Provider=MSOLEdbSQL;Integrated Security=sspi;Initial Catalog=%DBInstanceName%; Datasource=%DBServer%;"
set CN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set DB = CN.openDatabase (cs)

End Function

I was doing the above to connect to a sql server, but keep getting the error msg below:
"Operation is not allowed when the object is closed." How do I open the ADODB object? Thanks in advance.

CN.Open CS assuming you've replaced those placeholders in CS . There's no return value.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-connection?view=sql-server-ver16
